# Как получить данные из предыдущей строки в SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite

В отсортированной таблице нужно получить значение из предыдущей строки. Хотел использовать `WHERE ROWID=ROWID-1`, но это не работает. Как быть?

Запрос:

```
SELECT number
FROM codes
WHERE ROWID=ROWID-1
ORDER BY number ASC,id DESC
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Конечно не работает. Вы пытаетесь вывести, образно говоря, `2=1`, что, естественно, выведет пустой результат. Используйте соединение таблиц:

```
SELECT c1.number, c2.number as prev_number
FROM codes c1 left join codes c2 on c1.rowid = c2.rowid-1
ORDER BY c1.number, c1.id DESC
```

Comment: Спасибо, общий принцип понял. А как сделать, чтобы предыдущее значение бралось и присоединялось из уже отсортированных таблиц, а не сначала присоединялось, а потом сортировалось?

Comment: @ShmeLo а какая разница? Сортировка и так, и так одинаковая. Поменяйте параметры сортировки, если хотите сортировать по-другому. А для спасибо есть галочка напротив ответа :)

Comment: Хмм... в таком случае мне нужно присоединять предыдущие значения не по ROWID, а по порядковому номеру строк в уже отсортированной таблице. Его можно как то получить? Хотел сделать его в виде накопительной суммы по полю с единицей, но не обнаружил такой функции.

Comment: @ShmeLo Покажите пример вашей таблицы и желаемый результат. можно на sqlfiddle.com, чтобы лучше понять, что вам надо.